# Install trusted Certificate on stunnel

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, stunnel

I would like to be able to use a trusted certificate on Stunnel proxy, The default one does not seem to allow me to do this. Is there a way to do this please? Would need to be free.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your stunnel config file, use either `CAfile` or `CApath` and point it to your certificate. If you're doing client authentication, make sure you're on the latest version of stunnel and set `engine = capi` and `engineID = capi`.

Comment: thanks, There is no option for this. [https]
accept  = 8443
connect = 8090
cert = stunnel.pem

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that there isn't an option for that. You have to add it to the config file. What version of stunnel for Windows are you running?

Comment: I am running the latest one on Windows, 2nd July 2018. Where do I put it on the config file?

Comment: Here's an example Windows stunnel config: https://www.stunnel.org/config_windows.html You put `engine = capi` in the global portion, you put `engineID = capi` in each section that needs the CAPI engine. (This is for client auth stuff). Otherwise, `CAfile` and `CApath` also go in the global config portion of the file.

Comment: thanks heaps, Can I use a .crt file from Lets encrypt?

Comment: Probably - no reason why it wouldn't. You'll probably have to use `openssl` or something similar to convert it to a x.509 file to something more preferable to Windows.